# Null Reference ASP.Net MVC Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity, datacontext

On this line _repository.CreateDealer(d);
I get the error below.

I have started to base my code from the basics of this tutorial
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=786

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 84:             {
Line 85: 
Line 86:                 _repository.CreateDealer(d);
Line 87:             }
Line 88:             //DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer =


Source File: C:\Users\Scott\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DealerTentSaleMVC\DealerTentSaleMVC\Controllers\EdmundsController.cs    Line: 86 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DealerTentSaleMVC.Controllers.EdmundsController.Create(String zip, String make) in C:\Users\Scott\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DealerTentSaleMVC\DealerTentSaleMVC\Controllers\EdmundsController.cs:86
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +227
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8972317
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

DealerRepository.cs

```
    public void CreateDealer(DealersTemp.DealerHolder dealer)
{
    using (DealerContext context = new DealerContext())
    {
        context.Entry(new DealersTemp.DealerHolder
        {
            //DealerHolderId = dealer.DealerHolderId,
            id = dealer.id,
            locationId = dealer.locationId,
            address = dealer.address,
            name = dealer.name,
            logicalName = dealer.logicalName,
            type = dealer.type,
            make = dealer.make,
            operations = dealer.operations,
            contactinfo = dealer.contactinfo,
            publishDate = dealer.publishDate,
            active = dealer.active,
            syncPublishDate = dealer.syncPublishDate
        }).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

IDealerRepository.cs

```
    namespace DealerTentSaleMVC.Repository
{
    public interface IDealerRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<DealersTemp.DealerHolder> GetAllDealers();
        void CreateDealer(DealersTemp.DealerHolder dealer);
        DealersTemp.DealerHolder ReadDealer(int id);
        void UpdateDealer(DealersTemp.DealerHolder dealer);
        void DeleteDealer(int id);
    }

}
```

DealersTemp.cs

```
    namespace DealerTentSaleMVC.Models
{
    public class DealersTemp
    {
        public class Address
        {
            //public int AddressId { get; set; }
            public string street { get; set; }
            public string apartment { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string stateCode { get; set; }
            public string stateName { get; set; }
            public string county { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public string zipcode { get; set; }
            public double latitude { get; set; }
            public double longitude { get; set; }
            //public virtual int DealerHolderId { get; set; }
        }

        public class Operations
        {
            //public int OperationsId { get; set; }
            public string Wednesday { get; set; }
            public string Tuesday { get; set; }
            public string Thursday { get; set; }
            public string Saturday { get; set; }
            public string Friday { get; set; }
            public string Monday { get; set; }
            public string Sunday { get; set; }
            //public virtual int DealerHolderId { get; set; }
        }

        public class Contactinfo
        {
            //[Key]
            //public int ContactinfoId { get; set; }

            public string dealer_website { get; set; }
            public string email_address { get; set; }
            public string phone { get; set; }
            //public string phone_areacode { get; set; }
            //public string phone_postfix { get; set; }
            //public string phone_prefix { get; set; }
            //public virtual int DealerHolderId { get; set; }
        }

        public class DealerHolder
        {
            //[Key]
            //public int DealerHolderId { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string locationId { get; set; }
            public Address address { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string logicalName { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string make { get; set; }
            public Operations operations { get; set; }
            public Contactinfo contactinfo { get; set; }
            public string publishDate { get; set; }
            public bool active { get; set; }
            public string syncPublishDate { get; set; }

            public DealersTemp.DealerHolder ToDomainDealer()
            {
                return new DealersTemp.DealerHolder
                {
                    //DealerHolderId = this.DealerHolderId,
                    id = this.id,
                    locationId = this.locationId,
                    address = this.address,
                    name = this.name,
                    logicalName = this.logicalName,
                    type = this.type,
                    make = this.make,
                    operations = this.operations,
                    contactinfo = this.contactinfo,
                    publishDate = this.publishDate,
                    active = this.active,
                    syncPublishDate = this.syncPublishDate

                };
            }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<DealerHolder> dealerHolder { get; set; }
        }


    }
```

EdmundsController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string zip, string make)
{
    string url = "http://api.edmunds.com/v1/api/dealer?zipcode=" + zip.Replace(" ", "") + "&makeName=" + make.Replace(" ", "") + "&radius=3000&fmt=json&api_key=SomeKey";
    //WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string stws = wc.DownloadString(url);

    JToken root = JObject.Parse(stws);
    JToken dealerholder = root["dealerHolder"];
    DealerTentSaleMVC.Models.DealersTemp.DealerHolder convertedProducts = new DealerTentSaleMVC.Models.DealersTemp.DealerHolder();
    string dh = dealerholder.ToString().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
    Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(stws); 


    foreach (DealersTemp.DealerHolder d in result.DealerHolder)
    {

        _repository.CreateDealer(d);
    }


    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

DealerContext.cs

```
    namespace DealerTentSaleMVC.Context
{
    public class DealerContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<DealersTemp.DealerHolder> Dealers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the Full Json string

```
    {
    "dealerHolder": [
        {
            "id": "31711",
            "locationId": "3730",
            "address": {
                "street": "24825 US Hwy 19 N",
                "apartment": "",
                "city": "Clearwater",
                "stateCode": "FL",
                "stateName": "Florida",
                "county": "Pinellas",
                "country": "USA",
                "zipcode": "33763",
                "latitude": 27.99785,
                "longitude": -82.729321
            },
            "name": "Countryside Ford of Clearwater",
            "logicalName": "CountrysideFordofClearwater",
            "type": "ROOFTOP",
            "make": "Ford",
            "operations": {
                "Wednesday": "8:30 AM-9:00 PM",
                "Tuesday": "8:30 AM-9:00 PM",
                "Thursday": "8:30 AM-9:00 PM",
                "Saturday": "8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
                "Friday": "8:30 AM-9:00 PM",
                "Monday": "8:30 AM-9:00 PM",
                "Sunday": "11:00 AM-5:00 PM"
            },
            "contactinfo": {
                "dealer_website": "http://www.clearwaterford.com/",
                "email_address": "",
                "phone": ""
            },
            "publishDate": "2012-05-25",
            "active": true,
            "syncPublishDate": "2012-05-25"
        },
        {
            "id": "31673",
            "locationId": "3708",
            "address": {
                "street": "2525 34th St N",
                "apartment": "",
                "city": "Saint Petersburg",
                "stateCode": "FL",
                "stateName": "Florida",
                "county": "Pinellas",
                "country": "USA",
                "zipcode": "33713",
                "latitude": 27.794484,
                "longitude": -82.679411
            },
            "name": "Autoway Ford of St Petersburg",
            "logicalName": "AutowayFordofStPetersburg",
            "type": "ROOFTOP",
            "make": "Ford",
            "operations": {
                "Wednesday": "08:30 AM-08:00 PM",
                "Tuesday": "08:30 AM-08:00 PM",
                "Thursday": "08:30 AM-08:00 PM",
                "Saturday": "09:00 AM-06:00 PM",
                "Friday": "08:30 AM-08:00 PM",
                "Monday": "08:30 AM-08:00 PM",
                "Sunday": "12:00 PM-05:00 PM"
            },
            "contactinfo": {
                "dealer_website": "http://www.autowayford.net/",
                "email_address": "",
                "phone": ""
            },
            "publishDate": "2012-05-25",
            "active": true,
            "syncPublishDate": "2012-05-25"
        },
        {
            "id": "31636",
            "locationId": "3684",
            "address": {
                "street": "5815 N Dale Mabry Hwy",
                "apartment": "",
                "city": "Tampa",
                "stateCode": "FL",
                "stateName": "Florida",
                "county": "Hillsborough",
                "country": "USA",
                "zipcode": "33614",
                "latitude": 28.00016,
                "longitude": -82.505206
            },
            "name": "Bill Currie Ford",
            "logicalName": "BillCurrieFord",
            "type": "ROOFTOP",
            "make": "Ford",
            "operations": {
                "Wednesday": "8:00 AM-9:00 PM",
                "Tuesday": "8:00 AM-9:00 PM",
                "Thursday": "8:00 AM-9:00 PM",
                "Saturday": "8:00 AM-8:00 PM",
                "Friday": "8:00 AM-9:00 PM",
                "Monday": "8:00 AM-9:00 PM",
                "Sunday": "11:00 AM-6:00 PM"
            },
            "contactinfo": {
                "dealer_website": "http://billcurriedirect.dealerconnection.com/",
                "email_address": "",
                "phone_areacode": "888",
                "phone_postfix": "1156",
                "phone_prefix": "255",
                "phone": "8882551156"
            },
            "publishDate": "2012-05-25",
            "active": true,
            "syncPublishDate": "2012-05-25"
        },
        {
            "id": "31723",
            "locationId": "3739",
            "address": {
                "street": "17556 US 19 N",
                "apartment": "",
                "city": "Clearwater",
                "stateCode": "FL",
                "stateName": "Florida",
                "county": "Pinellas",
                "country": "USA",
                "zipcode": "33764",
                "latitude": 27.93164,
                "longitude": -82.730647
            },
            "name": "Walker Ford",
            "logicalName": "WalkerFord",
            "type": "ROOFTOP",
            "make": "Ford",
            "operations": {
                "Wednesday": "8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
                "Tuesday": "8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
                "Thursday": "8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
                "Saturday": "8:30 AM-6:00 PM",
                "Friday": "8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
                "Monday": "8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
                "Sunday": "11:30 AM-6:00 PM"
            },
            "contactinfo": {
                "dealer_website": "http://www.walkerford.com/",
                "email_address": "",
                "phone_areacode": "727",
                "phone_postfix": "3673",
                "phone_prefix": "535",
                "phone": "7275353673"
            },
            "publishDate": "2012-05-25",
            "active": true,
            "syncPublishDate": "2012-05-25"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the update showing the entire Controller Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DealerTentSaleMVC.Models;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;
using DealerTentSaleMVC.Repository;

namespace DealerTentSaleMVC.Controllers
{
    public class EdmundsController : Controller
    {
        private static string GetApiKey() { return "AIzaSyDiOm4qmnR7ZPbPPiUJrIxfYZ0XreDMaW8"; }

        private DealersTemp.RootObject db = new DealersTemp.RootObject();
        private IDealerRepository _repository;
        //
        // GET: /Edmunds/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(_repository.GetAllDealers());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Edmunds/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            DealersTemp.DealerHolder dealerholder = _repository.ReadDealer(id);

            return View(dealerholder);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Edmunds/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Edmunds/Create
        public class Result
        {
            public ICollection<DealersTemp.DealerHolder>DealerHolder { get; set; }
        }
        //[HttpPost]
        //public ActionResult Create(BlogPost blogpost)
        //{
        //    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //    {
        //        _repository.CreateBlogPost(blogpost);
        //        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //    }

        //    return View(blogpost);
        //}
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string zip, string make)
        {
            string url = "http://api.edmunds.com/v1/api/dealer?zipcode=" + zip.Replace(" ", "") + "&makeName=" + make.Replace(" ", "") + "&radius=3000&fmt=json&api_key=8rqtk3bb4bc4xgydqspvmc2s";
            //WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string stws = wc.DownloadString(url);

            JToken root = JObject.Parse(stws);
            JToken dealerholder = root["dealerHolder"];
            DealerTentSaleMVC.Models.DealersTemp.DealerHolder convertedProducts = new DealerTentSaleMVC.Models.DealersTemp.DealerHolder();
            string dh = dealerholder.ToString().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
            Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(stws); 


            foreach (var d in result.DealerHolder)
            {
                DealersTemp.DealerHolder newD = new DealersTemp.DealerHolder { active=d.active, contactinfo=d.contactinfo, address=d.address, id=d.id, locationId=d.locationId, logicalName=d.logicalName, make=d.make, name=d.name, operations=d.operations, publishDate=d.publishDate, syncPublishDate=d.syncPublishDate, type=d.type };


                _repository.CreateDealer(d);
            }
            //DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer =
            //        new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DealersTemp.RootObject));
            //DealersTemp.RootObject products = (DealersTemp.RootObject)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(ws.GetResponseStream());
            //List<DealersTemp.DealerHolder> convertProducts = (DealersTemp.DealerHolder)products.dealerHolder;


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Edmunds/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            DealersTemp.DealerHolder dealer = _repository.ReadDealer(id);

            return View(dealer);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Edmunds/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(DealerTentSaleMVC.Models.DealersTemp.DealerHolder dealerholder)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _repository.UpdateDealer(dealerholder);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(dealerholder);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Edmunds/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            DealersTemp.DealerHolder dealer = _repository.ReadDealer(id);
            return View(dealer);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Edmunds/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            _repository.DeleteDealer(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not show all of the controller code or the registration, so my best guess is you are not registering the dependency properly and _repository is null. Hard to tell though with the missing code.

Comment: Did you make sure `_repository` and `d` are not null?

Comment: private IDealerRepository _repository;

Comment: I just updated with the entire controller code

Comment: d is not null I debugged and it shows as not being null

Comment: I Added this to the top 
public EdmundsController(IDealerRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

Comment: After I added that now when I run the page I get the following error No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Comment: Please read through the article what you've linked! From point 6. However the MVC Framework calls the BlogPostController and by default it expects an empty constructor... you will find there how to solve this: you need a controller factory which creates your controller with the required dependencies.

Comment: Thank you too all of you. If one of you will click on answer question and place your answer there i will make sure to select it. I got it working now